# Drop everything from a string before a specific word?

Tags: ruby

How can I remove everything in a string before a specific word (or including the first space and back)?

I have a string like this:

```
12345 Delivered to: Joe Schmoe
```

I only want `Delivered to: Joe Schmoe`

So, basically anything from the first space and back I *don't* want.

I'm running Ruby 1.9.3.

Answer (score 3):

Use a regex to select just the part of the string you want.

```
"12345 Delivered to: Joe Schmoe"[/Delive.*/]
# => "Delivered to: Joe Schmoe"
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite a few different ways are possible. Here are a couple:

```
s = '12345 Delivered to: Joe Schmoe'
s.split(' ')[1..-1].join(' ') # split on spaces, take the last parts, join on space
# or
s[s.index(' ')+1..-1] # Find the index of the first space and just take the rest
# or
/.*?\s(.*)/.match(s)[1] # Use a reg ex to pick out the bits after the first space
```

Answer (score 0):

If Delivered isn't always the 2nd word, you can use this way:

```
s_line = "12345 Delivered to: Joe Schmoe"
puts s_line[/\s.*/].strip #=> "Delivered to: Joe Schmoe"
```